# Update query in vb.net doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, sql-update

I have an issue with update statement. This is my vb.net server side code:

```
Public Function UpdateRow() As DataTable

    Dim query As String = "Update Intranet.dbo.Gn_ISCoordinators SET cUserName='" & tbUsername.Text.Trim() &
        "',lDeptUser=" & CByte(rblDept.SelectedIndex) & " WHERE cUserName=" & "'" & Session("Edit") & "'"
    Dim hehe As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Using adapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter(query, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IntranetConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        adapter1.Fill(hehe)
        Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx")
        Session("Edit") = Nothing
        Return hehe
    End Using

End Function
```

And I'm calling it here:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
If Not Session("Edit") Is Nothing Then
        UpdateRow()
End If
```

I want the query which get the data from textbox and the data from RadioButtonList and update it with the one on the database. In my situation, the `Session("Edit")` is the same as the field where i want to replace it with the textbox's text. When I press on the button it doesn't give me any change. Where is the problem exactly?

Please help me.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are running an update query. You need to execute it with ExecuteNonQuery, the Fill command of the adapter reads data from the database not write to it. And your data is not in the database

```
Public Function UpdateRow() As DataTable

    Dim query As String = "Update Intranet.dbo.Gn_ISCoordinators SET cUserName=@uname" +  
                          ",lDeptUser=@dept WHERE cUserName=@oldName"
    Using con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IntranetConnectionString").ConnectionString)    
         con.Open()
         Dim cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", tbUsername.Text.Trim())
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept", CByte(rblDept.SelectedIndex))
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldname", Session("Edit"))
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Function
```

Note also that you should never concatenate strings to form sql commands. This approach lead to a very seriuos security problem called [Sql Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)

Comment: It gives me a green line under `End Function` and writes `A null reference exception could be occur`. In addition, it doesnn't work with me.

Comment: Don't have errors rather than the green line. But it doesn't work. i don't know why. after i press the button it just keep the username as it is. as if i didn't do anything.

Comment: And after the update what do you expect to see in the tbUsername textbox?

Comment: I should see the new username and the table is updated with the new username. isn't it?

Comment: I suppose the oldusername is stored in session("Edit") and the newusername is stored in tbUsername textbox. Is it not so?

Comment: Yeah its correct. the old one is in session and the new one is in the tbusername.